# PropertySource is loading the file property as null when a custom annotation is present in AppConfig

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to use a custom PropertySource annotation which basically fetches a property file from AWS S3 folder. This custom annotation is called "S3PropertySource". The issue is that when I am using @S3PropertySource and @PropertySource, then the property file loaded through @PropertySource seems to be getting loaded twice, and in the first attempt, the property values of the file are null. Although, as per startup logs, I see that the file is loaded again and this time the property has values.

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@Import({KafkaProducerConfig.class, RestConfig.class})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:config/dev/local.properties"})
@S3PropertySource(url = "s3://some-folder-location/mapping/s3PropertyFile.properties")
public class AppConfig { 

@Value("${x.property.from.local.properties.file}")
  private String url; // this property is coming from "local.properties" file loaded through PropertySource

@Bean
  String getPropertyFromLoalPropertiesFile() {
    LOGGER.info("End Point : {}", url);
    return url;
  }
```

As per the start up logs:

```
INFO  AppConfig - End Point : null
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
INFO  AppConfig - End Point : http://url.from.local.properties.file/api
```

The S3 file is being loaded fine, as I can check from the logs.
Note:

- this error is happening only after @S3PropertySource is added to AppConfig file.

This is how S3PropertySource is defined.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Documented
@Import({S3PropertiesLoader.class})
@Repeatable(S3PropertySources.class)
public @interface S3PropertySource {
    String url();

    boolean required() default true;
}
```

To summarize, I have following questions:
1.how can I fetch property both from S3 and from property file present in resources folder.
2. what can be another way to read the file from S3 and have the property available throughout the project, without making the property a bean.

Thanks!